# Add Database Field from Mysql Stored Procedure in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I'm using Mysql Stored Procedure in Crystal Reports ..
my stored procedure return more fields than in this image .

How i can add these other fields ?

[image]

Comment: *Drag* the field and *drop* it at *detail* or *group* section.

Comment: i mean other fields witch are not displayed  from my sp?

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying stored procedure

if so then you have to reload the stored procedure from database expert.

Once you reloaded the same will reflect in above explorer